# horizontal menu using css and html

Tags: html, css

![menu example][1]

i would like to create web site page as follows. Top area contains the office information and logo etc. Next line will have horizontal menu with vertical drop down submenus, vertical menu will drop only when mouse is over it, every entry in vertical menu has hyperlink document, which should be displayed in content area which is below the menu area, without hiding / overlapping the horizontal menu. Can it be done using css and html, pl help, so that menu is elegant and professional also, i tried using frames but vertical menu is hidden by the frame. Also tried putting menu and hyperlink target in same window, but then menu disappears. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it can be done, what have you tried?

Comment: Do you want us to write the code for you?

Answer (score 0):

If your struggling with HTML & CSS thats ok... We all had to start somewhere, and to be honest I still have style issues after 3 years of university studying! The important thing is to perserve and not let someone else do all the work for you, this will aid your personal development and you will get a great sense of accomplisement when you turn that blank page into a fully functioning dynamic website!

A great book that got me started and I still refer to from time to time is this -

[http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learning-Web-Design-Beginners-JavaScript-ebook/dp/B00ANW18T2/ref=sr_1_3?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1401363603&sr=1-3&keywords=html+for+beginners][1]](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learning-Web-Design-Beginners-JavaScript-ebook/dp/B00ANW18T2/ref=sr_1_3?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1401363603&sr=1-3&keywords=html+for+beginners%5d%5b1%5d)

My advice - start of small, do a few header tags, paragraph tags and start to play about with stying like changing color and size. When you feel like this is boring you, prehaps move onto tables and div tags to change the layout and design of your page. After you have done all that stuff you may want to try abit of javascript for form handling and menu bars.

Then... Why stop there!? You can then decide to learn a server side language like PHP or ASP.net and do some really cool stuff like having a login form for your users that gives them access to a special membership area.

Don't forget StackOverFlow though there are some great guys and gals on here that will help you out almost as soon as you have posted the question (just make sure you give them something to work to, and if you are not great at wording things like me.. get someone to proof read it first!).

Have fun codeing :) It's a bitch at times, but nothing easy is worth doing in life!